# Transpose a 1-dimensional array in Numpy without casting to matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, transpose

My goal is to to turn a row vector into a column vector and vice versa. The documentation for [`numpy.ndarray.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) says:

> For a 1-D array, this has no effect. (To change between column and row vectors, first cast the 1-D array into a matrix object.)

However, when I try this:

```
my_array = np.array([1,2,3])
my_array_T = np.transpose(np.matrix(myArray))
```

I do get the wanted result, albeit in matrix form (`matrix([[66],[640],[44]])`), but I also get this warning:

> **PendingDeprecationWarning**: the matrix subclass is not the recommended way to represent matrices or deal with linear algebra (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). Please adjust your code to use regular ndarray.
>
> ```
> my_array_T = np.transpose(np.matrix(my_array))
> ```

How can I properly transpose an `ndarray` then?

Comment: It looks like that suggestion in the docstring should be removed or changed to not recommend using `numpy.matrix`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A 1D array is itself once transposed, contrary to Matlab where a 1D array doesn't exist and is at least 2D.

What you want is to reshape it:

```
my_array.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Or:

```
my_array.reshape(1, -1)
```

Depending on what kind of vector you want (column or row vector).

The `-1` is a broadcast-like, using all possible elements, and the `1` creates the second required dimension.

Comment: `my_array[:, None]` also does the needed reshape.

Comment: Agreed, that's also one way of doing reshape.

Answer (score 2):

If your array is `my_array` and you want to convert it to a column vector you can do:

```
my_array.reshape(-1, 1)
```

For a row vector you can use

```
my_array.reshape(1, -1)
```

Both of these can also be transposed and that would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `reshape`

```
my_array.reshape(my_array.size, -1)
```

Comment: There is an extra hing here, you probably mean (-1, 1), the -1 in this case is really a 1.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher either `1` and `-1` are ok ;)

Comment: Yes, except that -1 does an additional computation, the easiest is (-1, 1).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher The time difference would be *really really* negligible, but still fair point ;)