# How do I can get array like this array([[1], [2], [3]]) using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes 2 parameters and returns a shape of an array.
The output should be like this: `array(\[\[A\], \[B\], \[B\]\])`, but I got it like this: `array(\[\[A, B, C\]\])`.

What is the methoud that I can use to return it like this: `array(\[\[A\], \[B\], \[B\]\])`

For example, `initialise_array(3,1)` will return an array of dimensions `(3,1)` that can look like this:

```py
array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])
```

My code:

```py
def initialise_array(n_features, n_observations): 
    shape = np.random.rand(n_features, n_observations) 
    n_shape = shape.reshape(n_observations, n_features) 
    return n_shape
```

The output looks like `array([[0.85546058, 0.70365786, 0.47417383]])` but I need to match the this `array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])`

Comment: just do `return np.array([[A], [B], [B]])`. But you want to return B twice and discard C?

Comment: What 2 parameters? And how is array([[A], [B], [B]]) the shape of the arraay? This question makes zero sense, also no code ....

Comment: @JosipJuros ,@Sembei Norimaki


def initialise_array(n_features,n_observations):
    shape = np.random.rand(n_features,n_observations)
    n_shape = shape.reshape(n_observations,n_features)
    return n_shape

the output looks like array([[0.85546058, 0.70365786, 0.47417383]]) but I need to match the this array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])

Comment: @mohammadsadoun You gotta be shitting me. You couldnt edit the question and post that code in it?

Answer (score 1):

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(repr(a))

a=a[0]
print(repr(a))

a=np.reshape(a,np.shape(a)+(1,))
print(repr(a))
```

Output :

```
array([[1, 2, 3]])
array([1, 2, 3])
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

You can also do it by other ways :
[Transforming a row vector into a column vector in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384760/transforming-a-row-vector-into-a-column-vector-in-numpy)

```
a[:,np.newaxis]
```

```
a.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Congrats on your first answer! where you did provide answer to the OP, it would good to add a little explanation why does this work as expected.