# How do I can get array like this array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]]) using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that takes 2 parameters and returns a shape of an array. where the function that will create a Numpy array of a given shape with random values.
The output should be like this: `array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])`, but I got it like this: `arrayarray([[0.37454012, 0.95071431, 0.73199394]]))`.

What is the methoud that I can use to return it like this: `([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])`

For example, `initialise_array(3,1)` will return an array of dimensions `(3,1)` that can look like this:

```py
array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])
```

My code:

```py
def initialise_array(n_features, n_observations): 
    shape = np.random.rand(n_features, n_observations) 
    n_shape = shape.reshape(n_observations, n_features) 
    return n_shape
```

The output looks like `array([[0.85546058, 0.70365786, 0.47417383]])` but I need to match the this `array([[0.37454012], [0.95071431], [0.73199394]])`

Comment: Then use `shape.reshape(n_features, n_observations)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I can get array like this array(\[\[1\], \[2\], \[3\]\]) using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574607/how-do-i-can-get-array-like-this-array1-2-3-using-numpy)

Comment: Please do not repost your own question that already has an answer.

Comment: doesn't work I need the output looks like this array ([[1],[2],[3]]), not like this array([[1, 2,3]]), shell i use for loop ?

Comment: Sorry @MichaelSzczesny, I tried to deleted but not work :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just get rid of your reshape call

```
def initialise_array(n_features, n_observations): 
    shape = np.random.rand(n_features, n_observations) 
    return shape
```

Output:

```
>>> initialise_array(3, 1)
array([[0.38454951],
       [0.61060765],
       [0.84899489]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that parameters passed to *np.random.rand* define just the
**shape** of the array to be created.

So much shorter and simpler code than yours is:

```
def initialise_array(n_features, n_observations): 
    return np.random.rand(n_features, n_observations)
```

When you call this function as: `initialise_array(3, 1)` you will get
an array with 3 rows and a single column. Just as you wish.

And a remark about your code:

It is misleading in the way you use variable names.

Note that what you save under *shape* variable is not any **shape**,
but an **array** (of the shape passed with parameters).