# numpy reshape confusion with negative shape values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Always confused how numpy reshape handle negative shape parameter, here is an example of code and output, could anyone explain what happens for reshape [-1, 1] here? Thanks.

Related document, using Python 2.7.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

S = np.array(['box','apple','car'])
le = LabelEncoder()
S = le.fit_transform(S)
print(S)
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
one_hot = ohe.fit_transform(S.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(one_hot)

[1 0 2]
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -1 mean in numpy reshape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-1` is used to infer one missing length from the other. For example reshaping `(3,4,5)` to `(-1,10)` is equivalent to reshaping to `(6,10)` because `6` is the only length that makes sense form the other inputs.

Comment: Thanks Julien, in your example, it is 3 dimensional array 3*4*5? So, if after reshape we need to have # of columns to be 10, the rows need to be 6, is that the correct calculation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes: the input array has `3*4*5 = 60` elements. The output will have `n_rows * 10` elements, and so we need to solve for `n_rows * 10 = 60` which gives `n_rows = 6`.

Comment: Thanks Julien, but how do they handle if multiple -1?

Comment: It can't because it is ambiguous, as mentioned in the docs, or by the error thrown if you try...

Comment: Thanks Julien for the help, going to mark your reply as answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

From `reshape` docs:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred
>   from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

In your case it is used for the common task of transforming the (3,) `S` into a (3,1) array. I think in this particular case using `S[:, None]` would have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Aguy, when you say `(3,)`, a bit confused by the syntax, what does the `,` mean here?

Comment: Just to design a tuple. `(3)` is `3`, `(3,)` is the tuple with a single element `3`. (shapes are tuples, even if they contain only one element)

Comment: You can think about `(n,)` numpy object as a vector and `(n,1)` as a matrix of just 1 column.

Comment: Thanks Aguy, but if `(3,)` means only one element in a tuple, how you are going to transform it to be shape of `(3,1)`? I think `(3,1)` means 3 rows * 1 column, which is 3 elements?

Comment: @JulienBernu, but if `(3,)` means only one element in a tuple, how you are going to transform it to be shape of `(3,1)`? I think `(3,1)` means 3 rows * 1 column, which is 3 elements?

Comment: `(3,)` still means 3 elements, just like `(3,1)` or `(3,1,1,1,...,1)`. `(3,)` means the object is a 1d array. `(3,1)` means it is a 2d array (although the second dimension is 1). It is actually a column vector. `(1,3)` would represent a row vector (but still as a 2d array). Makes sense? You can try to print all those versions and you'll see some subtle differences in where/how many brackets appear.