# How to visualize images in tensorboard using tf.summary.image() in [batch, channels, width, height] (NCHW) order?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

First, I want to reshape the 2-D to 4-D tensor using `tf.reshape()`.
I thought `tf.reshape()` will transform
`[batch, array]` -> `[batch, width, height, channels]` (NHWC) order
but in practice it transformed
`[batch, array]` -> `[batch, channels, width, height]` (NCHW) order

Example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]])
print(a.shape)

# [batch_size, channels, height, width]
b = sess.run(tf.reshape(a, shape=[2, 3, 4, 4]))

# [batch_size, height, width, channels]
c = sess.run(tf.reshape(a, shape=[2, 4, 4, 3]))

print(b)
print('*******')
print(c)
```

The result was:

```
(2, 48)
[[[[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]]


 [[[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11 12]
   [13 14 15 16]]]]
*******
[[[[ 1  2  3]
   [ 4  5  6]
   [ 7  8  9]
   [10 11 12]]

  [[13 14 15]
   [16  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]]

  [[ 9 10 11]
   [12 13 14]
   [15 16  1]
   [ 2  3  4]]

  [[ 5  6  7]
   [ 8  9 10]
   [11 12 13]
   [14 15 16]]]


 [[[ 1  2  3]
   [ 4  5  6]
   [ 7  8  9]
   [10 11 12]]

  [[13 14 15]
   [16  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]]

  [[ 9 10 11]
   [12 13 14]
   [15 16  1]
   [ 2  3  4]]

  [[ 5  6  7]
   [ 8  9 10]
   [11 12 13]
   [14 15 16]]]]
```

So, I changed `data_format='channels_first'` for conv and pooling layers to using the reshaped tensor in NCHW order. In fact, the training was good. *`--verbose:`* it gave better result, as mention by @mrry in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396970/tensorflow-3-channel-order-of-color-inputs/47704862#47704862), and I think it could be understandable because NCHW is the default order of cuDNN.

However, I can not add image to summary using `tf.summary.image()`, [which is documented here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image), because the required tensor shape should be in `[batch_size, height, width, channels]` order.

Moreover, if I train and visualize the input images in `[batch, width, height, channels]` order, it represented incorrect images.
[image]
And I worth to mention that, the training result was not as good as using `[batch, channels, width, height]` order.

There are several questions:
**1. Why** `tf.reshape()` transform `[batch , array]` -> (NCHW) order instead of (NHWC) order ? I tested with both tf CPU and GPU, same result. I also used np.reshape(), also same result. *(This's why I think I could misunderstand something here)*
**2. How** can I visualize images in tensorboard using tf.summary.image() in (NCHW) order? (**question #2 solved** using advice from **@Maosi Chen**. Thanks)
[image]

I've trained the model on *GPU (version 1.4)*, the images are from *CIFAR-10* dataset.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the dimensions by `tf.transpose` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose).

Note that `perm` elements are the dimension indices of the source tensor (`a`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]])
print(a.shape)

# [batch_size, channels, height, width]
b = sess.run(tf.reshape(a, shape=[2, 3, 4, 4]))

# [batch_size, height, width, channels]
c = sess.run(tf.transpose(b, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1]))

print(b)
print('*******')
print(c)
```

Results:

```
(2, 48) [[[[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]]


 [[[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]

  [[ 1  2  3  4]    [ 5  6  7  8]    [ 9 10 11 12]    [13 14 15 16]]]]
******* [[[[ 1  1  1]    [ 2  2  2]    [ 3  3  3]    [ 4  4  4]]

  [[ 5  5  5]    [ 6  6  6]    [ 7  7  7]    [ 8  8  8]]

  [[ 9  9  9]    [10 10 10]    [11 11 11]    [12 12 12]]

  [[13 13 13]    [14 14 14]    [15 15 15]    [16 16 16]]]


 [[[ 1  1  1]    [ 2  2  2]    [ 3  3  3]    [ 4  4  4]]

  [[ 5  5  5]    [ 6  6  6]    [ 7  7  7]    [ 8  8  8]]

  [[ 9  9  9]    [10 10 10]    [11 11 11]    [12 12 12]]

  [[13 13 13]    [14 14 14]    [15 15 15]    [16 16 16]]]]
```

Comment: I tried difference `perm` combinations but it seems not working as we expected. Also according to my example above, which `tf.transpose()` do you think it should be ?

Comment: Please see the added example.

Comment: The visualize worked. Thanks.     
What do you think about the question #1 ?

Comment: It must be originally ordered that way. You need to know the original order before you reshape and transpose it to the desired 4D tensor.

Comment: I agreed. It's a bit vague because when I used the MNIST, which the channels=1, `tf.reshape()` work fine for training and visualization on tensorboard.