# collapsing all dimensions of numpy array except the first two

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable dimension numpy array, for example it could have the following shapes

```
(64, 64)
(64, 64, 2, 5)
(64, 64, 40)
(64, 64, 10, 20, 4)
```

What I want to do is that if the number of dimensions is greater than 3, I want to collapse/stack everything else into the third dimension while preserving order. So, in my above example the shapes after the operation should be:

```
(64, 64)
(64, 64, 10)
(64, 64, 40)
(64, 64, 800)
```

Also, the order needs to be preserved. For example, the array of the shape `(64, 64, 2, 5)` should be stacked as

```
(64, 64, 2)
(64, 64, 2)
(64, 64, 2)
(64, 64, 2)
(64, 64, 2)
```

i.e. the 3D slices one after the other. Also, after the operation I would like to reshape it back to the original shape without any permutation i.e. preserve the original order.

One way I could do is multiply all the dimension values from 3 to the last dimension i.e.

```
shape = array.shape
if len(shape) > 3:
    final_dim = 1
    for i in range(2, len(shape)):
        final_dim *= shape[i]
```

and then reshape the array. Something like:

```
array.reshape(64, 64, final_dim)
```

However, I was first of all not sure if the order is preserved as I want and whether there is a better pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify on the stacking, like for the sample `a` : `(64, 64, 2, 5)`, where should `a[:,:,:,0]` be placed in `out` with `out` being the output array?

Comment: Keep in mind that in `numpy` the last dimension is the inner most one.  If you iterate on a (N,2,3) array, you work with N (2,3) arrays.  MATLAB uses the reverse order; 1st is inner most, last outer most.  The way the languages display a 3d array reflects that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reshape accept automatic re-dimension :

```
a=rand(20,20,8,6,4)
s=a.shape[:2]
if a.ndim>2 : s = s+ (-1,)
b=a.reshape(s)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: As pointed out in the other answers it is even easier to just provide -1 as the third dimension for `reshape`. Numpy automatically determines the correct shape then.

I am not sure what the problem here is. You can just use `np.reshape` and it preserves order. See the following code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(20,20,2,2,18,5)
print A.shape

new_dim = np.prod(A.shape[2:])
print new_dim
B = np.reshape(A, (A.shape[0], A.shape[1], np.prod(A.shape[2:])))
print B.shape

C = B.reshape((20,20,2,2,18,5))
print np.array_equal(A,C)
```

The output is:

```
(20L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 5L)
360
(20L, 20L, 360L)
True
```

This accomplishes exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Try `.reshape(64, 64, -1)`; see this recent question about -1 in reshape: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776579/what-does-1-in-numpy-reshape-mean

Comment: Ah very nice. I thought in the back of my head that there was something like this, but could not remember. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the requirement of stacking for the given `(64, 64, 2, 5)` sample, I think you need to permute the axes. For the permuting, we can use [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html), like so -

```
def collapse_dims(a):
    if a.ndim>3:
        return np.rollaxis(a,-1,2).reshape(a.shape[0],a.shape[1],-1)
    else:
        return a
```

Sample run on the given four sample shapes -

1) Sample shapes :

```
In [234]: shp1 = (64, 64)
     ...: shp2 = (64, 64, 2, 5)
     ...: shp3 = (64, 64, 40)
     ...: shp4 = (64, 64, 10, 20, 4)
     ...:
```

Case #1 :

```
In [235]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(shp1))

In [236]: np.allclose(a, collapse_dims(a))
Out[236]: True
```

Case #2 :

```
In [237]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(shp2))

In [238]: np.allclose(a[:,:,:,0], collapse_dims(a)[:,:,0:2])
Out[238]: True

In [239]: np.allclose(a[:,:,:,1], collapse_dims(a)[:,:,2:4])
Out[239]: True

In [240]: np.allclose(a[:,:,:,2], collapse_dims(a)[:,:,4:6]) # .. so on
Out[240]: True
```

Case #3 :

```
In [241]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(shp3))

In [242]: np.allclose(a, collapse_dims(a))
Out[242]: True
```

Case #4 :

```
In [243]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(shp4))

In [244]: np.allclose(a[:,:,:,:,0].ravel(), collapse_dims(a)[:,:,:200].ravel())
Out[244]: True

In [245]: np.allclose(a[:,:,:,:,1].ravel(), collapse_dims(a)[:,:,200:400].ravel())
Out[245]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to illustrate the concern that `@Divaker` brings up.

```
In [522]: arr = np.arange(2*2*3*4).reshape(2,2,3,4)
In [523]: arr
Out[523]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]],


       [[[24, 25, 26, 27],
         [28, 29, 30, 31],
         [32, 33, 34, 35]],

        [[36, 37, 38, 39],
         [40, 41, 42, 43],
         [44, 45, 46, 47]]]])
```

4 is the inner most dimension, so it displays the array as 3x4 blocks.  And if you pay attention to spaces and [] you'll see there are 2x2 blocks.

Notice what happens when we use the `reshape`:

```
In [524]: arr1 = arr.reshape(2,2,-1)
In [525]: arr1
Out[525]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]]])
```

Now it is 2 2x12 blocks.  You can do anything to those 12 element rows, and reshape them back to 3x4 blocks

```
In [526]: arr1.reshape(2,2,3,4)
Out[526]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
      ...
```

But I could also split this array on the last dimension.  `np.split` can do it, but a list comprehension is easier to understand:

```
In [527]: alist = [arr[...,i] for i in range(4)]
In [528]: alist
Out[528]: 
[array([[[ 0,  4,  8],
         [12, 16, 20]],

        [[24, 28, 32],
         [36, 40, 44]]]), 
 array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
         [13, 17, 21]],

        [[25, 29, 33],
         [37, 41, 45]]]), 
 array([[[ 2,  6, 10],
         [14, 18, 22]],

        [[26, 30, 34],
         [38, 42, 46]]]), 
 array([[[ 3,  7, 11],
         [15, 19, 23]],

        [[27, 31, 35],
         [39, 43, 47]]])]
```

This contains 4 (2,2,3) arrays.  Note that the 3 element rows display as columns in the 4d display.

I can reform into a 4d array with `np.stack` (which is like `np.array`, but gives more control of how the arrays are joined):

```
In [529]: np.stack(alist, axis=-1)
Out[529]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
         ...
        [[36, 37, 38, 39],
         [40, 41, 42, 43],
         [44, 45, 46, 47]]]])
```

==========

The `split` equivalent is `[x[...,0] for x in np.split(arr, 4, axis=-1)]`.  Without the indexing split produces (2, 2, 3, 1) arrays.

`collapse_dims` produces (for my example):

```
In [532]: np.rollaxis(arr,-1,2).reshape(arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1],-1)
Out[532]: 
array([[[ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11],
        [12, 16, 20, 13, 17, 21, 14, 18, 22, 15, 19, 23]],

       [[24, 28, 32, 25, 29, 33, 26, 30, 34, 27, 31, 35],
        [36, 40, 44, 37, 41, 45, 38, 42, 46, 39, 43, 47]]])
```

A (2,2,12) array, but with the elements in rows in a different order.  It does a transpose on the inner 2 dimensions before flattening.

```
In [535]: arr[0,0,:,:].ravel()
Out[535]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [536]: arr[0,0,:,:].T.ravel()
Out[536]: array([ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11])
```

Restoring that back to the original order requires another roll or transpose

```
In [542]: arr2.reshape(2,2,4,3).transpose(0,1,3,2)
Out[542]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

      ....

        [[36, 37, 38, 39],
         [40, 41, 42, 43],
         [44, 45, 46, 47]]]])
```