# numpy optimize way(remove loops)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I want to use this code on very huge array. this code take long time to execute and it is not efficient.
is there any way to remove loop and convert this code to optimum way?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.random.randint(10, size=(4,5,3))
>>> x
array([[[3, 2, 6],
        [4, 6, 6],
        [3, 7, 9],
        [6, 4, 2],
        [9, 0, 1]],

       [[9, 0, 4],
        [1, 8, 9],
        [6, 8, 1],
        [9, 4, 5],
        [1, 5, 2]],

       [[6, 1, 6],
        [1, 8, 8],
        [3, 8, 3],
        [7, 1, 0],
        [7, 7, 0]],

       [[5, 6, 6],
        [8, 3, 1],
        [0, 5, 4],
        [6, 1, 2],
        [5, 6, 1]]])
>>> y=[]
>>> for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range(x.shape[2]):
        y.append(x[:, i, j].tolist())


>>> y
[[3, 9, 6, 5], [2, 0, 1, 6], [6, 4, 6, 6], [4, 1, 1, 8], [6, 8, 8, 3], [6, 9, 8, 1], [3, 6, 3, 0], [7, 8, 8, 5], [9, 1, 3, 4], [6, 9, 7, 6], [4, 4, 1, 1], [2, 5, 0, 2], [9, 1, 7, 5], [0, 5, 7, 6], [1, 2, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could permute axes with `np.transpose` and then reshape to `2D` -

```
y = x.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,x.shape[0])
```

Append with `.tolist()` for list output.

Comment: what dose reshape(-1.. do ?

Comment: @pdshah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776579/what-does-1-in-numpy-reshape-mean

Answer (score 2):

yes, either use `np.reshape(x, shape)` or try it with `np.ndarray.flatten(x, order='F')` (F for Fortran style, column first, according to your example).

read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to find out which parameters fit the best. IMHO, I think `ndarray.flatten` is the better and more elegant option for you here. However, depending on your exact wanted solution, you might have to reshape the array first.