# Numpy concatenate arrays with interleaving

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 4 arrays and I want to concatenate them into one single array with interleaving. How do I do this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.tile(0,(5,2))
>>> b = np.tile(1,(5,2))
>>> c = np.tile(2,(5,2))
>>> d = np.tile(3,(5,2))
>>> e = np.concatenate((a,b,c,d),axis=1)
>>> e
    array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]])
```

This gives just the concatenation.

However, my desired_output is:

```
>>> desired_output
    array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

I mean I know I can select the interleaved columns from e using:

```
>>> f = e[:, ::2]
>>> array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

But how do I make one big array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) or [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to stack along the last axis that gives us a `3D` array and then reshape back to `2D` -

```
np.dstack([a,b,c,d]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
np.stack([a,b,c,d],axis=2).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks man! That was really fast. Do you do this for a living or what? =)

Comment: @bFig8 Mostly ;)

Comment: @bFig8 If you are asking about that `-1`, here's something to help out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776579/.

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome. I wonder what the "d" in `dstack` stands for ?