# NumPy arrays to C arrays

Tags: python, arrays, c, numpy, reshape

Can somebody help with `reshape` NumPy function. I'm trying to convert pyhton code to the C code and stack with `reshape` of array.

Content of `myfile.txt`:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4
5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8
```

Python code:

```
fly_data = np.loadtxt('myfile.txt', dtype = 'float')

print(fly_data)

fly_reshaped = np.reshape(fly_data, [-1, 2, 1])

print(fly_reshaped)
print("reshaped [0] -> ", fly_reshaped[0])
print("reshaped [1] -> ", fly_reshaped[1])
print("reshaped [0][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[0][0])
print("reshaped [0][1] -> ", fly_reshaped[0][1])
print("reshaped [1][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[1][0])
print("reshaped [1][1] -> ", fly_reshaped[1][1])
print("reshaped [0][0][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[0][0][0])
print("reshaped [0][1][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[0][1][0])
print("reshaped [1][0][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[1][0][0])
print("reshaped [1][1][0] -> ", fly_reshaped[1][1][0])
```

Output:

```
fly_data:
[[1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4]
 [5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8]]

fly_reshaped:
[[[1.1]
  [2.2]]

 [[3.3]
  [4.4]]

 [[5.5]
  [6.6]]

 [[7.7]
  [8.8]]]

reshaped [0]    ->  [[1.1]
                     [2.2]]
reshaped [1]    ->  [[3.3]
                     [4.4]]
reshaped [0][0] ->  [1.1]
reshaped [0][1] ->  [2.2]
reshaped [1][0] ->  [3.3]
reshaped [1][1] ->  [4.4]
reshaped [0][0][0] ->  1.1
reshaped [0][1][0] ->  2.2
reshaped [1][0][0] ->  3.3
reshaped [1][1][0] ->  4.4
```

The C fly_data can be represented as 2d array

```
double fly_data[2][4] = { { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 },
                          { 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8 } };
```

But I'm completely lost with the fly_reshape after. Is my understanding correct that after reshape I get 3d array:

```
double test[4][2][1] = {{{1.1},
                         {2.2},},

                        {{3.3},
                         {4.4},},

                        {{5.5},
                         {6.6},},

                        {{7.7},
                         {8.8},},};
```

I read `fly_data` from the file it's mean that initial size is unknown that's why I'm get rows and columns from the file then allocate space for `fly_data` and then read values in the `fly_data`. I don't want to post the whole code just put a little snippet with some simplification:

```
    double **fly_data = NULL;

    // get rows from a file
    while (EOF != (fscanf(fptr, "%*[^\n]"), fscanf(fptr, "%*c")))
            size++;

    rows = size;
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fly_data = malloc(sizeof(double *) * (size + 1));
    //skip check for malloc fails

    // check how many double values per line in a file ex: [1.1 2.2] == 2, [1.1 2.2 3.3] == 3 
    while ((fgets(buffer, 4096, fptr)) != NULL) {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

        double_in_str = 0;
        ch = strtok(buffer, " ");
        double_in_str++;
        while ((ch = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
            double_in_str++;
        }

        fly_data[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (double_in_str + 1));
        //skip check for malloc fails
   
        s_cols = double_in_str;
        i++;
    }

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Then I do pretty much the same as above to fill the `fly_data` array and as a result at the end I'v got:

```
cols == 4;
rows == 2;
double **fly_data --> [[1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4]
                       [5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8]]
```

But I don't know how to transform it to the 3d array as NumPy reshape does... Maybe there is some similar libraries like NumPy for C? Will appreciate any advice's...

**UPDATE:**
I may have confused everyone, I'm trying to convert python code to C and before main calculation in python code reshape is done with 2d array as a result the new shape is unclear for me I will post steps how array is changed during python code

```
Initial look of fly_data:
[[46.67346954 78.40816498 22.40816307 ... 84.06122589 45.32653046
  21.06122398]
 [47.29680252 77.16743469 24.18564224 ... 82.65706635 45.0110817
  21.70456314]
 [47.40319824 77.37702942 24.22916985 ... 82.59411621 45.39061737
  21.66947556]
 ...
 [48.68153381 77.01563263 23.45227432 ... 84.76795959 39.03504944
  25.56122208]
 [48.40353775 76.80964661 23.60672569 ... 84.90617371 39.11692429
  25.81131935]
 [48.43016052 77.01958466 23.49253464 ... 84.92854309 39.21281052
  25.75781631]]

Look after reshape: reshaped = np.reshape(fly_data, [-1, 64,3])

[[[46.67346954 78.40816498 22.40816307]
  [57.83673477 15.75510216 66.20407867]
  [74.20407867 14.73469353 62.55102158]
  ...
  [30.4285717  80.4897995  33.95918274]
  [33.12244797 73.69387817 33.81632614]
  [84.06122589 45.32653046 21.06122398]]

 [[47.29680252 77.16743469 24.18564224]
  [58.2369957  18.34436035 66.55934906]
  [73.53372955 16.48843384 62.20281219]
  ...
  [31.12094307 78.90615082 33.91459656]
  [32.91826248 71.42383575 32.91826248]
  [82.65706635 45.0110817  21.70456314]]

 [[47.40319824 77.37702942 24.22916985]
  [58.36494446 18.34773445 66.74745941]
  [73.50817871 16.47192955 62.31195831]
  ...
  [31.10712814 79.09651947 34.03807831]
  [33.0415535  71.14387512 33.02201462]
  [82.59411621 45.39061737 21.66947556]]

 ...

 [[48.68153381 77.01563263 23.45227432]
  [55.06695938 19.15627098 69.02896881]
  [70.61067963 16.14906693 65.43595123]
  ...
  [35.24675751 78.61687469 29.85722733]
  [33.56741333 71.17697144 32.51293564]
  [84.76795959 39.03504944 25.56122208]]

 [[48.40353775 76.80964661 23.60672569]
  [55.52457809 19.08047485 68.92773438]
  [70.62507629 16.13451195 65.02579498]
  ...
  [35.13694763 78.7020874  29.98639297]
  [33.38107681 71.38595581 32.50314331]
  [84.90617371 39.11692429 25.81131935]]

 [[48.43016052 77.01958466 23.49253464]
  [55.3431778  19.09866905 68.58335876]
  [70.49713135 16.05225563 65.40024567]
  ...
  [35.18997955 78.58184814 29.91734314]
  [33.43243408 71.47354889 32.5731926 ]
  [84.92854309 39.21281052 25.75781631]]]

At next step I'm totally lost how it can be represented in C (Above steps is now more clear what happens):

p1 = reshaped[:,:,0]

[[46.67346954 57.83673477 74.20407867 ... 30.4285717  33.12244797
  84.06122589]
 [47.29680252 58.2369957  73.53372955 ... 31.12094307 32.91826248
  82.65706635]
 [47.40319824 58.36494446 73.50817871 ... 31.10712814 33.0415535
  82.59411621]
 ...
 [48.68153381 55.06695938 70.61067963 ... 35.24675751 33.56741333
  84.76795959]
 [48.40353775 55.52457809 70.62507629 ... 35.13694763 33.38107681
  84.90617371]
 [48.43016052 55.3431778  70.49713135 ... 35.18997955 33.43243408
  84.92854309]]
```

If you take a look after reshape the values for `reshape` starts from `46.67346954 78.40816498 22.40816307`
So I assume that  `p1 = reshaped[:,:,0]` make p1 starts from `46.67346954 78.40816498 22.40816307` like in reshaped array but it's starts from another direction `46.67346954 57.83673477 74.20407867` like if we will count reshaped like `reshaped[0][0] reshaped[1][0] reshaped[2][0] etc...` I just need explanation what `[:,:,0]` does?

Comment: Is it really necessary for your use case to have 2d data represented in a 3D array? I mean, the last dimension is 1 anyway, so you are in fact not using this dimension.

Comment: `fly_data` is a (2,4) shaped array.  The reshape makes a (4,2,1) array.  What's the purpose of that reshape?  `numpy` arrays store the data a 1d `c` array, and use the `shape` to interpret it as multidimensional array.  `loadtxt` loads the file into a list of lists, and makes the array from that.

Comment: It's easy (and efficient) to append to a list, so by building a list of lists, the `loadtxt` code doesn't need to know, ahead of time, how many rows there are.  Once you have a list of lists, it's easy to make an array,  `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`.  Reshape just makes a `view`, with the same data, but a different `shape` (and `strides`).  With this `strided` array definition, reshape is easy.

Comment: Please do not use jagged arrays. They are not efficient and prevent any fast reshape. Actually, AFAIK Numpy do not use jagged arrays internally too but flatten ones.

Comment: @MaxPowers I just trying to rewrite python code to C line by line and during debugging python code to understand what happens I found out that it's done reshape before calculation. In my example I choose simple values like 1.1 2.2 etc but in real test file there is more data 2500+ new lines 64 values per line. reshape is done line `reshape(fly_data, [-1, 64, 3])` and after this line calculation is done. `p1 = reshaped[:,:,0]` p2 = reshaped[:,:,1]` `p3 = reshaped[:,:,2]` I didn't find what this syntax mean so I assume that they worked with 3d array in this case ...

Comment: @PetraGrygorenko For an explanation of the -1 syntax see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776579/what-does-1-in-numpy-reshape-mean/41777769#41777769).

Comment: @PetraGrygorenko The `[:, :, 0]` syntax is just an index in a 3d array, where `:` means just "consider all indices on this axis". See [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#).

Comment: @MaxPowers Thanks Max, its helpful! It's so painful to convert python code to c especially when works with such big arrays and matrices....