# Numpy reshape with negative values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm really new to the numpy and currently confused with negative values in reshape.

import numpy as np

```
a=np.arange(6)
c=a.reshape(1,3,2)
d=a.reshape(-1,3,2)
e=a.reshape(-1,1,2)
print c
print
print d
print
print e
```

and it returns

```
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]
  [4 5]]]

[[[0 1]
  [2 3]
  [4 5]]]

[[[0 1]]

 [[2 3]]

 [[4 5]]]
```

The question here is that when comparing c and d, there's no difference at all. However in e, additional empty line is formed between each row. So, what exactly does the -1 do in reshape function, and why it causes empty lines between each row in e? Thanks !

Comment: It is asked before and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510505/6900838) is a good explanation:

Comment: I clearly acknowledge that but that doesn't give me explanation on empty lines. That is what i am curious about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `c` and `e` is not only the additional space, but also the additional bracket around each pair, i.e.

```
[2 3]    vs    [[2 3]]
```

This is because the shape of `c` is `[1, 3, 2]`, while the shape of `e` is `[3, 1, 2]`. The shape of `d` is also `[1, 3, 2]`, and that is why `c` and `d` are equal.

When you put -1 in the shape, numpy infers it from the other dimensions, that is replaces -1 with `product of all dimensions of a / product of all specified shapes`

Answer (score 8):

When you add `-1` to an axis in numpy it will just put *everything else* in that axis. This is, for an array `a` of shape `(10, 10)`, the following operations will apply:

```
>>> a.reshape(-1, 10, 10) # a is (1, 10, 10)
>>> a.reshape( 1, 10, 10) # a is also (1, 10, 10)
>>> a.reshape(-1, 5, 5)   # a is (4, 5, 5), since 4 * 5 *  5 = 100
>>> a.reshape(-1, 5, 10)  # a is (2, 5, 10) since 2 * 5 * 10 = 100
```

This is, when reshaping the total number of elements must be the same, so adding `-1` to the shape just lets numpy calculate the remaining value for you, so that the product of the axes still matches the previous number of elements.