# Index out of bounds error : Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of data that is not smooth. Hence I'm trying to interpolate it with the generated mesh.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('test.txt')
x=data[:,0] #len(x) = 730
y=data[:,1]

Nx= len(x)
Ny=len(y)
del_x= 0.5
xn = np.linspace(0,Nx,2000)
yn = np.linspace(0,Ny,2000)

#loop 
for i in range(0,Nx-1):
 if x[i] > xn[i] and x[i] < xn[i+1]:
  new_x= (i + (xn[i] - x[i])/(xn[i]-xn[i+1]))*del_x
print new_x
```

I would like to perform the loop that basically does the operation i.e : if my original data x[i] is in between the two grid points xn[i],xn[i+1], then compute new_x.

But I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "new.py", line 27, in <module>
  if x[i] > xn[i] and x[i] < xn[i+1]:
IndexError: index out of bound
```

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @U8-Forward I have updated with more explanation.

Comment: You seem to be aware that python ranges are in the form `[0, N[`. What is `len(x)`? From your definition of `xn` I am guessing that the source of the indexing error is that the list `x` is too short.

Comment: @SigveKarolius len(x) = 730.

Comment: @Goyo It is just a list. , x, y gives me a parabola

Comment: what's the size of the array 'data'? Maybe the array ‘’x‘’ don't have 1000 elements.

Comment: Ok, so your `for` loop throws an error when it is trying to access `x[730]` (remember that the first item in a Python list is regarded as "element 0").

Comment: @newstudent Your edited code does not raise any errors --with my data, I do not have yours.

Comment: @Goyo Heres my data     https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiuikxlosf6jqi3/profile_nonoisebigd02.txt?dl=0

Comment: @newstudent In a recent comment you describe a different problem. So what is your actual problem?

Comment: @Goyo need to calculate local curvature i.e at each point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[numpy linspace official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

`xn = np.linspace(0,Nx,2000)`

in here `0` is start value, `Nx` is end value and `2000` is the number of values to be generated.

returned object of linspace is something like :

`[0, 0.5, 1, ... , ] #2000 elements` i.e. a row containing 2000 elements

`x=data[:,0]`
x is something like :

`[[1],[2],[3],[4], .... ,[]] #column vector with number of elements in text data`

now row size of x can not be greater than `1` ie index has to be less than `1` or equal to `0`

and you can't compare these two arrays

`[ ... ]` and `[[], [], [], [],  ... ]`

are incomparable (you can compare the first element though.)

you could use this : [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

refer to this answer : [What does -1 mean in numpy reshape?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510505/6546530)

`row_x = x.reshape(-1)`

will give you a row vector.

and you can convert to column format by:

`col_x = row_x.reshape(-1,1)`

*I would appreciate edits as I am currently at work and thus wrote the answer in hurry.*

Answer (score 0):

If `len(x) = 730` than its too short for the loop. Your loop iterates `1000` times, `i` would be at some point bigger than `730` and there are no values like `x[730]`,`x[731]` etc. You will get an out of bound error because you are accessing not existing values in an array.

Comment: Thanks, So I need to make Nx, Ny  = 730?

Comment: Better do Nx=Len(x), Ny=len(y). Than its dynamic and you will be not supposed to change something if the datafile changes

Comment: I did that, but the error persists, Is there any error in the if loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your for loop like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(x)):
```

Answer (score 0):

## First some basics

1. Python is "zero indexed", meaning that the first element in the list is indexed as `0`.
2. Ranges are given as: `[start, stop[`, meaning that the last element is not included.

Just see what happens if you try:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print("a has %d elements:" %(len(a)))
for i in range(len(a)):
  print("a[%d] = %d" %(i, a[i]))
```

The output is:

```
a has 3 elements:
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
```

If you try to access `a[3]` you will see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

## Now to your problems

Numpy "linspace" takes the following input: `numpy.linspace(start, stop, N)`, resulting in a closed range `[start, stop]` (notice it includes the "stop") with `N` elements.

You want the number of elements, or `len(xn)` to be 730, and I am **guessing** you want the "stop" value to be `max(x)`:

```
xn = numpy.linspace(0, max(x), len(x))

for i in range(len(x)):
  ...
```

> **Tip:**
>   If you are uncertain about the signature of a function you can always ask for `help`, try:`help(numpy.linspace)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed ans, but looks like the loop only calculates for a single i , rather than for all  in range.

Comment: So no `IndexError` at least... Now your problem that the "if statement" is only `true` **once**.