# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

While practicing Simple Linear Regression Model I got this error, 
I think there is something wrong with my data set.

[Here is my data set:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb0od.jpg)

[Here is independent variable X:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5wJN.jpg)

[Here is dependent variable Y:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuJUA.jpg)

[Here is X_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtkGZ.jpg)

[Here Is Y_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQu8K.jpg)

This is error body:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 7.   8.4 10.1  6.5  6.9  7.9  5.8  7.4  9.3 10.3  7.3  8.1].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

And this is My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pt

#import data set

dataset = pd.read_csv('Sample-data-sets-for-linear-regression1.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

#Spliting the dataset into Training set and Test Set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= 0.2, random_state=0)

#linnear Regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to give both the [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) and [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict) methods 2D arrays. Your `x_train` and `x_test` are currently only 1 dimensional. What is suggested by the console should work:

```
x_train= x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

This uses numpy's [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to transform your array. For example, `x = [1, 2, 3]` wopuld be transformed to a matrix `x' = [[1], [2], [3]]` (-1 gives the x dimension of the matrix, inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions, 1 is the y dimension - giving us a n x 1 matrix where n is the input length).

Questions about `reshape` have been answered in the past, this for example should answer what `reshape(-1,1)` fully means: [What does -1 mean in numpy reshape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape) (also some of the other below answers explain this very well too)

Comment: You should not reshape the `y_train` since you want it as 1D array.

Comment: i have no idea why this is needed ;(

Comment: @WestCoastProjects If you read the documentation for [sklearn fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit), the input X and Y must both be 2D arrays, to quote the documentation X is an: ` {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)`

Answer (score 29):

A lot of times when doing linear regression problems, people like to envision this graph

[image: one variable input linear regression]

On the input, we have an X of X = [1,2,3,4,5]

However, many regression problems have multidimensional inputs. Consider the prediction of housing prices. It's not one attribute that determines housing prices. It's multiple features (ex: number of rooms, location, etc. )

If you look at the documentation you will see this
[image: screenshot from documentation]

It tells us that rows consist of the samples while the columns consist of the features.

[image: Description of Input]

However, consider what happens when we have one feature as our input. Then we need an n x 1 dimensional input where n is the number of samples and the 1 column represents our only feature.

Why does the `array.reshape(-1, 1)` suggestion work? -1 means choose a number of rows that works based on the number of columns provided. See the image for how it changes in the input.
[image: Transformation using array.reshape]

Comment: Nice explanation, i think that this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Well-explained, it is easy to follow the thoughts.

Comment: What a joy to read an answer which takes the time to consider _why_ the question was asked. Very helpful for us google searchers arriving with similar but non-identical issues.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at documentation of [`LinearRegression` of scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> X : numpy array or sparse matrix of shape [n_samples,n_features]
>
> predict(X)
>
> X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = (n_samples, n_features)

As you can see `X` has 2 dimensions, where as, your `x_train` and `x_test` clearly have one.
As suggested, add:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Before fitting and predicting the model.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
y_pred = regressor.predict([[x_test]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to reshape X at the beginning before you do the split into train and test dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pt

#import data set

dataset = pd.read_csv('Sample-data-sets-for-linear-regression1.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
# Here is the trick
x = x.reshape(-1,1)

#Spliting the dataset into Training set and Test Set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= 0.2, random_state=0)

#linnear Regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use

```
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
regressor.predict([[x_test]])
```

And for polynomial regression:

```
regressor_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[x_test]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
```

to

```
regressor.fit(x_train.values.reshape(-1,1),y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the array is 1-D and I wanted a 2-D array.
I wanted to convert my array to [[1,2,3,4,...]] instead of [[1],[2],[3],...] for which I used the below code:
`regressor.predict(np.array([X]))`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35491983)