# simulation of linear regression scikit-learn python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, simulation

I would like to run a linear regression but this code generates an error starting from "reg = LinearRegression()"

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy.stats import binom

from scipy.stats import norm
# generate random numbers from N(0,1)
x = norm.rvs(size=10000,loc=0,scale=1)
y = norm.rvs(size=10000,loc=0,scale=1)
z = binom.rvs(n=10,p=0.8,size=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'v1':x.flatten(),'target':y.flatten(),'label':z.flatten()})
df.head(10)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df['v1'], df["target"])
```

error message:
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.39507346 -0.01013895 -0.83918156 ...  0.47254883  0.02202747
0.50782984].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

any hint about what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150153/valueerror-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.values.reshape(-1, 1)`:

```
reg.fit(df['v1'].values.reshape(-1, 1), df["target"].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: thanks, it works but I don't understand why my version gives problems..

Comment: If it helps then close the question by marking this as a solution. Merry christmas in advance :)