# How to reshape an array in Python using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (10,) array I want to reshape in (1,10)

I did the following (u being my array)

```
import numpy as np

u = u.reshape(-1,1).T
```

but it does not work, any advice ?

Comment: Try `u.reshape(1, -1)`

Comment: np.expand_dims(u, axis=0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -1 mean in numpy reshape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Chris in his comment you simply want to reshape the array by fixing the number of rows to one and [let Python figure out the other dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape):

```
u=u.reshape(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think @Chris has mentioned well in the comment, you can try out

I have tried out the scenario

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> u = np.zeros((10))

>>> u.shape
(10,)
>>> u.T
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> u = u.reshape(1, -1)
>>> u.shape
(1, 10)
>>> u.T
array([[0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   [0.]])
```

I think for your case `u.reshape(1, -1)` would do your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `expand_dims()` method.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(10) # a.shape = (10,)
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
print(a.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is :

```
u = u.reshape((-1, 1)).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick in the book that works is with `np.newaxis`

```
 u = u[np.newaxis,:]
```

Should give you an array with shape `(1,10)`