# How to fix "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"?

Tags: python, deep-learning, sklearn-pandas

When running:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)
```

I am getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yp4j.png)

After that I tried:

```
train = train.array.reshape(-1, 1)
```

And I got:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'array'
```

How can I reshape by data to fix the value error?

Comment: Could you please check `type(train)` and `train.shape`?

Comment: the type is list. but when using shape I am getting 

"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Comment: Edit the tags to show which package(s) you are using.  `deep-learning` is too generic and over-used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `train = np.array(train).reshape(-1, 1)`.

It appears `train` is originally a list. So you must convert it into an array using `np.array()`. Then, you can use the `.reshape()` method to change the dimensions. `.reshape(-1, 1)` asks `numpy` to create a 2-dimensional matrix with a single column. `numpy` can infer the number of rows in this matrix since you only want one column. the `-1` parameter asks `numpy` to infer the length of the first dimension. Please see [this answer for a more complete understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510505/5500488).

Comment: the commands runs. However, I am still getting the error when I run `scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)`

Comment: what about train = np.array(train).reshape(-1,2) -> this makes it a 2d array

Comment: I think this does provide an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as potentially low-quality. Please elaborate on your answer so that new and future developers understand how your answer solves the OP's question.

Comment: I tried`train = np.array(train).reshape(-1,1)` and now when I run`scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)`, I get **DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype <U10 was converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)**. what does it mean?
`

Comment: This means that you have integers in your array but `StandardScaler()` requires floats to perform the computation. This should not affect your output but you should clarify for your self the difference between ints and floats in python numerical representation.