# Keras: How to Multiply()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

**TensorFlow 2.0 RC1**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Multiply

import numpy as np
```

Expected output:

```
Multiply()([np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4]).reshape(2,3), np.array([1,0])])
```

[image]

Problem:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(None,3))
mask_1 = Input(shape=(None,))

net = Multiply()([input_1, mask_1])
net = Model(inputs=[input_1, mask_1], outputs=net)

net.predict([np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4]).reshape(1,2,3), np.array([1,0]).reshape(1,2)]) # 1 = batch size
```

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of dimensions should match, by modifying the input shape of the 2nd input to `(None, 1)` and adding an extra-dimension to the `[1, 0]` array

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Multiply
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input

input_1 = Input(shape=(2,3))
mask_1 = Input(shape=(2,1))

net = Multiply()([input_1, mask_1])
net = Model(inputs=[input_1, mask_1], outputs=net)

net.summary()

print(net.predict([np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4]).reshape((1,2,3)), np.array([1,0]).reshape((1,2,1))]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Reshape the second array in the last line of code as `np.array([1,0]).reshape(-1)`

```py
net.predict([np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4]).reshape(1,2,3), np.array([1,0]).reshape(-1)]) # 1 = batch size
```

Comment: For further information about `.reshape(-1)` you can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape)

Comment: Thanks @Physicing for the add-on

Comment: @stephen_mugisha Thank you for you answer! But this does not work.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev what error are you getting when you use this method?

Comment: `ValueError: Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (2, 2, 3), expected output shape = shape (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev do you mind showing you input dimensions?? Your output is 2-dimensional and you need to reduce it to 1-dimensional

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the input shape is specified. In the Multiply() example(element-wise multiplication), the batch size is 2 and the feature size is 3 for Input and 1 for mask. So, when specifying the input shape in Keras, only the feature size needs to be specified.

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(3,))
mask_1 = Input(shape=(1,))
net = Multiply()([input_1, mask_1])
net = Model(inputs=[input_1, mask_1], outputs=net)
output = net.predict([np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4]).reshape(2,3), np.array([1,0])])
print(output)
```

[[1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do character embedding. So in my example batch size is 1. 2 words of 3 characters.