# Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

While I am predicting the one sample from my data, it gives reshape error but my model has equal number of rows. Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2.0 , 2.4, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 3.7])
y = np.array([196, 221, 136, 255, 244, 230, 232, 255, 267])

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x,y)

print(lr.predict(2.4))
```

The error is

```
if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=2.4.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 
single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: if you want to know why fitting a model requires 2d model -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367841/why-does-the-fit-method-in-sklearns-linearregression-only-accept-2d-array-for-t)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should reshape your X to be a 2D array not 1D array. Fitting a model requires requires a 2D array. `i.e (n_samples, n_features)`

```
x = np.array([2.0 , 2.4, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 3.7])
y = np.array([196, 221, 136, 255, 244, 230, 232, 255, 267])

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)

print(lr.predict([[2.4]]))
```

Comment: Thanks man. But what's that reshape does  and why not using it causes error.

Comment: @razzOn2bull When fitting a model your X needs to be 2D array. i.e (n_samples, n_features). When you use `.reshape(1, -1)` it adds one dimension to the data. You can see this question ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape') for more info regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically saying to convert the flat feature array into a column array. `reshape(-1, 1)` does the job; also `[:, None]` can be used.

The second dimension of the feature array `X` must match the second dimension of whatever is passed to `predict()` as well. Since `X` is coerced into a 2D array, the array passed to `predict()` should be 2D as well.

```py
x = np.array([2.0 , 2.4, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 3.7])
y = np.array([196, 221, 136, 255, 244, 230, 232, 255, 267])
X = x[:, None]         # X.ndim should be 2

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

prediction = lr.predict([[2.4]])
```

If your input is a pandas column, then use double brackets (`[[]]`) get a 2D feature array.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': x, 'target': y})
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(df['feature'], df['target'])            # <---- error
lr.fit(df[['feature']], df['target'])          # <---- OK
#        ^^         ^^                           <---- double brackets
```

###### Why should `X` be 2D?

If we look at the source code of `fit()` (of any model in scikit-learn), one of the first things done is to validate the input via the [`validate_data()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L648-L650) method, which calls [`check_array()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/base.py#L584) to validate `X`. `check_array()` checks among other things, whether `X` is 2D. It is essential for `X` to be 2D because ultimately, `LinearRegression().fit()` calls `scipy.linalg.lstsq` to solve the least squares problem and `lstsq` [requires `X` to be 2D](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c1ed5ece8ffbf05356a22a8106affcd11bd3aee0/scipy/linalg/_basic.py#L1157-L1158) to perform matrix multiplication.

For classifiers, the second dimension is needed to get the number of features, which is essential to get the model coefficients in the correct shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lr.predict([[2.4]])` instead of `lr.predict(2.4)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your providing that was not provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58663856/12846804 posted 4 years before yours?