# Why does the fit method in sklearn's LinearRegression only accept 2D array for the x-values, but 1D arrays for the y-values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, numpy-ndarray

Basically just the title. It just struck me as odd when I was dipped my toes into the `sklearn` library. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: I guess that is for generalization purpose. In regression X can be multidimensional, and if it has only one dimension it can be still represented as a 2D array. Y consist in only one signal and therefore can be only a 1D array. Allowing a unique format avoids writing 'if' loops handling other formats and lowers the risk of having unexpected errors deeper in the code.

Comment: This might be a newbie question, but why can't Y be a multidimensional array?

Comment: This would mean that you are doing multi target regression, i.e. predicting several signals at the same time from the same training set. In this case Y would be a multidimensional array, actually [sklearn has an implementation for it](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) and you can see that Y is a mutidimensional array. However this is quite unusual, as most of regression problems wouldn't benefit from it. The implementation in sklearn is a just wrapper training multiple single-target regressor.

Comment: As a matter of fact though LinearRegression *does* accept a 2D target array, in which case it will perform a multiple linear regression

Comment: Yes, the main reason I asked this question was because I was confused as to why the x-values needed to be a 2D array, but like @A Co said, it's just for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way it is by design choice for the `fit` methods of ML models in scikit-learn afaik. It's mostly to stay consistent with the specification of the input shape: `(n_samples, n_features)`:

> ```
> X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
>      Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and
>      n_features is the number of features.
> ```

Which is also made clear right at the top of [`check_array`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/388999b59d0070fafdcd76cf599af6758b25d987/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L352), the validation step where the error is raised:

> ```
> Input validation on an array, list, sparse matrix or similar.
> By default, the input is checked to be a non-empty 2D array containing
> only finite values. If the dtype of the array is object, attempt
> converting to float, raising on failure.
> ```

`LinearRegression` *does* actually accept `2D` target arrays though, in which case it will perform a multiple linear regression.