# Python: KNN regression fitting returns error

Tags: python, machine-learning, curve-fitting, knn

I am working on a machine learning practice exercises and I keep getting an error when I run the following code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=51
SD=1.15
ME=0
E=np.random.normal(ME, SD, N)
X = np.linspace(-4,4, N, endpoint=True)
Y = X**2 + E

neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)
neigh.fit(X, Y)

X_eval = np.linspace(0,4,1000)
X_eval = X_eval.reshape(-1,1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_eval,neigh.predict(X_eval), label="regression predictor")
plt.plot(X,Y, 'rs', markersize=12, label="training set")
plt.show()
```

the error is on the neigh.fit() line and is:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[all the generated x-values].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

But fitting it this way does not work either. I am fairly new to machine learning and python programming so my apologies if this question is trivial but: What could I improve to make my code run?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial part to solving this is understanding the error. The error is telling you that you need to pass a 2-D array, but you only passed a 1-D array. To be more explicit, your problem is with `X`, which indeed needs to be reshaped as such:

```
X_new = X.reshape(-1,1)
```

`reshape(-1,1)` will take the 1-D array and make sure that each subarray only has 1 element in it. The -1 tells [`numpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape) to infer the number of subarrays to make; in this case, we get 51.

The code below runs in my terminal:

```
#UPDATED CODE
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=51
SD=1.15
ME=0
E=np.random.normal(ME, SD, N)
X = np.linspace(-4,4, N, endpoint=True)
X_NEW = X.reshape(-1,1)
Y = X**2 + E

neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)
neigh.fit(X_NEW, Y)

X_eval = np.linspace(0,4,1000)
X_eval = X_eval.reshape(-1,1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_eval,neigh.predict(X_eval), label="regression predictor")
plt.plot(X,Y, 'rs', markersize=12, label="training set")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please upvote/accept the answer if you found it helpful so others know that the problem is solved. happy to help @Kat