# How it is internally arrange to 1 D

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am reading over the internet regarding numpy, got stuck at this point

How the array is getting converted to 1 D

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

newa = arr.reshape(-1)

print(newa)
```

Output : `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: Because you supply the `reshape` method with just one argument: one argument, one resulting dimension.

Comment: Are you interested n the technical details how it works that the array becomes 1d? Or are you asking how reshape works and why it gives you a 1d array when you tell it you want a shape of -1? Your comments on the other question got me wondering.

Comment: @user2640045 : how reshape works and why it gives a 1d array want to know

Comment: @xawefog : May be this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why does reshape give you a 1d array for `arr.reshape(-1)`?

Well usually you give reshape a tuple of sizes you want your array to be reshaped to. E.g. if you have an array with 10 elements and you do `arr.reshape((5,2))` it gives you a 2d array that is 5 by 2.

```
arr = np.arange(10) -> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
arr.reshape((5,2)) -> array([[0, 1],
                             [2, 3],
                             [4, 5],
                             [6, 7],
                             [8, 9]])
```

If you had given reshape numbers that don't multiply to 10 like 3 and 5 it would give you an error. But if you know all but one of the dimensions and want numpy to figure out what to pick for the last one so it works out you can put a -1 there. E.g. `arr.reshape((5,-1))` and `arr.reshape((-1,2))` give you exactly the same result as `arr.reshape((5,2))`. Notice that sometimes it still does not work out even with -1. E.g. `arr.reshape((3,-1))` would raise an error. It's not possible to make a 3 by something array out of 10 numbers.

So if you do `arr.reshape(-1)` it means you want a 1d array containing all your numbers.

Comment: Thanks bro for making me understand with an example

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation:

> **newshape** : int or tuple of ints.
> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D
> array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the
> value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining
> dimensions.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: not getting what actually the meaning is

Comment: if i give -2 then gives me same result