# Python shape (ValueError) error when trying to compute a derivative with numpy - diff

Tags: python, numpy

I'm interested on calculating a derivative using `diff` from `numpy`. For this, I use two arrays `a` and `b` with shape `(N,)` try to compute `x`

```
N=int(1e4)
a=np.ones(N)
b=9*np.ones(N)

x=np.zeros((N,1)) #shape (10000, 1)
for j in range(N):
    x[j]=a[j]/b[j]
y=3*x - 1

doty=np.diff(y)/np.diff(b)
```

I find a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10000,0) (9999,)`.

Why does this happens?
How can I reshape `b` to match `x`?

Comment: Try `doty=np.diff(y.reshape(-1))/np.diff(b)`

Comment: Thanks @user17242583 , I didn't think the solution was that simple.  Should I close this question? ; I also think this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape) might be useful for someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
doty = np.diff(y.reshape(-1)) / np.diff(b)
```