# How to update a df using a for loop and arrays on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, debugging

Suppose that I create the following df:

```
import pandas as pd

#column names
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#create a dataframe including the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Then, I create the following array that will have the cell values to add to my `df`:

```
rows = ["2:00", "GBP", "", "Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)", "1.1%", "0.5%", "2.0%",
        "2:00", "GBP", "", "U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)", "9.9%", "9.2%", "7.4%"]
```

So, how can I use a for loop to update my `df` so it ends up like this:

```
|Time   |Currency  |Volatility expected    |Event                               |Actual   |Forecast   |Previous  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|02:00  |GBP       |                       |Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)     |1.1%     |0.5%       |2.0%      |
|04:00  |GBP       |                       |U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)|9.9%     |9.2%       |7.4%      |
```

I tried:

```
column_name_location = 0
for row in rows:
    df.at['0', df[column_name_location]] = row
    column_name_location += 1

print(df)
```

But got:

> KeyError: 0

May I get some advice here?

Comment: Is `rows` a list of two lists, each of length 7? Or is it a list of 14 strings?

Comment: I created a list of 14 strings sir @richardec

Comment: Okay. See my answer below. It accounts for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rows` is a flat list of items, you can convert it to a numpy array to reshape it first

Assuming `rows` is actualy a list of sub-lists, each sub-list being a row, you can create a `pd.Series` from each row using the dataframe's column names as the Series's index, and then use `df.append` to append them all:

```
df.append([pd.Series(r, index=df.columns) for r in rows])
```

If `rows` is actually just a flat list, you'll need to convert it to a numpy array to reshape it:

```
rows = np.array(rows).reshape(-1, 7).tolist()
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much sir, may you also please elaborate on the use of  `.reshape(-1, 7)`? I understand that as my `df` has 7 columns, it's expected to have `7` cells below each, but what's the `-1` used for?

Comment: @Noah basically it just says to reshape the array into an array of unknown rows and 7 columns. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have created one list containing 14 items.
You could instead make it as a list containing 2 items where each item is a list with 7 values.

```
rows = [["2:00", "GBP", "", "Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)", "1.1%", "0.5%", "2.0%"],
       ["2:00", "GBP", "", "U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)", "9.9%", "9.2%", "7.4%"]]
```

With this, we can create a dataframe directly as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
print(df)
```

**This outputs 2 rows**

```
   Time Currency Volatility expected                                 Event Actual Forecast Previous
0  2:00      GBP                           Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)   1.1%     0.5%     2.0%
1  2:00      GBP                      U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)   9.9%     9.2%     7.4%
```

Comment: This one will work pretty well after implementing @richardec's answer, but as I didn't know how to reshape the array, I had to mark richardec's answer as the solution I was looking for. But I also appreciate you took some time to answer this post .