# Reshape 3-d array to 2-d

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change my array type as `pd.DataFrame` but its shape is:

```
array_.shape
(1, 181, 12)
```

I've tried to reshape by the following code, but it didn't work:

```
new_arr = np.reshape(array_, (-1, 181, 12))
```

How can I change its shape?

Comment: How => with `reshape` method from numpy but what shape you want to get ?

Comment: `array_[0]`, IIUC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy array dimensions can be reduced using various ways; some are:
using [`np.squeeze`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape):

```
array_.squeeze(0)
```

using `np.reshape`:

```
array_.reshape(array_.shape[1:])
```

or with using [`-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691084/what-does-1-mean-in-numpy-reshape) in `np.reshape`:

```
array_.reshape(-1, m.shape[-1])

# new_arr = np.reshape(array_, (-1, 12))    # <==   change to your code
```

using `indexing` as [Szczesny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny):

```
array_[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to erase the `-1` parameter from the `reshape()` function to get a final output shape of `(181, 12)`

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[[1]*12]*181])
n = np.reshape(m, (181, 12))
print(m.shape, n.shape)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 181, 12) (181, 12)
```