# Divide list into sublist following certain pattern

Tags: python, arrays, list, sublist

Given an example list `a = [311, 7426, 3539, 2077, 13, 558, 288, 176, 6, 196, 91, 54, 5, 202, 116, 95]` with n = 16 elements (it will be in general a list of an even number of elements).

I wish to create n/4 lists that would be:

```
list1 = [311, 13, 6, 5]
list2 = [7426, 558, 196, 202]
list3 = [3539, 288, 91, 116]
list4 = [2077, 176, 54, 95]
```

(The solution is not taking an element every `n` such as `a[i::3]` in a for loop because values are excluded as the sliding window moves to the left)

Thanks for the tips!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the solutions which work well for this particular example. I realized however that my problem is a bit more complex than this.

In the sense that the list `a` is generated dynamically in the sense the list can decrease or increase. Now my issue is the following, say that the list grows of another group i.e. until 20 elements. Now the output lists should be 5 using the same concept. Example:

`a = [311, 7426, 3539, 2077, 1 ,13, 558, 288, 176, 1, 6, 196, 91, 54, 1, 5, 202, 116, 95, 1]`

Now the output should be:

```
list1 = [311, 13, 6, 5]
list2 = [7426, 558, 196, 202]
list3 = [3539, 288, 91, 116]
list4 = [2077, 176, 54, 95]
list5 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And so on for whatever size of the list.

Thanks again!

Comment: If you know that your list is a static size (say that they are always a length of 20), you can create a corresponding number of empty lists for as many increments as you want, then create a for loop going through the original list.

Then you can use if statements to check the current index and see which list you want to add to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the length of the list *a* is a multiple of 4. You can use numpy for your problem.

```
import numpy as np
a = [...]
desired_shape = (-1, len(a)//4)
arr = np.array(a).reshape(desired_shape).transpose().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[311, 13, 6, 5],
 [7426, 558, 196, 202],
 [3539, 288, 91, 116],
 [2077, 176, 54, 95],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Unpack the list into variables or iterate over them as desirable.

Consult [numpy.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), and [reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18691084/4720957) to understand their usage.

Comment: I've updated my question because I realized it's a bit more complex than this simple example. Thanks

Comment: @Diauro I've updated my code. See if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One option: nested list comprehension.

##### split in n/4 chunks of 4 items

```
out = [[a[i+4*j] for j in range(4)]
       for i in range(len(a)//4)]
```

Output:

```
[[311, 1, 176, 91],
 [7426, 13, 1, 54],
 [3539, 558, 6, 1],
 [2077, 288, 196, 5],
 [1, 176, 91, 202]]
```

##### split in 4 chunks of n/4 items

```
out = [[a[i+4*j] for j in range(len(a)//4)]
       for i in range(4)]
```

Output:

```
[[311, 1, 176, 91, 202],
 [7426, 13, 1, 54, 116],
 [3539, 558, 6, 1, 95],
 [2077, 288, 196, 5, 1]]
```

To split in lists:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = out
```

Although it is not easily possible to do this programmatically (and not recommended to use many variables)

Comment: I've updated my question because I realized it's a bit more complex than this simple example. Thanks

Comment: @Daurio see update